# Functional ground alternatives in a Class II equipment

Tags: emc, emi-filtering

Usually we build Class I equipment, i.e. with a ground lead. For EMC purposes we use an input filter (commercially bought).

For reference a typical filter is made in this way (source [electronics weekly](https://www.electronicsweekly.com/news/products/power-supplies/input-protection-filters-out-the-power-risks-2017-07/)) [image: Typical filter]

The idea is to shunt the noise with C1-C2 (X capacitors) and draining it to ground with Y-capacitors (C3 and C4). The magnetic parts also help filtering noise at different frequency. Also the power supply has it's own filtering stage needing a ground connection (only FG)

For various reasons (included people who don't have a ground terminal in their sockets!) we need to convert to Class II (double insulation), and that's a pain in itself.

However the bigger issue is that Class II equipment *cannot* have a ground lead, for safety (for fixed installations you can have a functional ground for this exact purpose but this is not the case). So now the filter has nowhere to dump the noise. It would somewhat work (all the inductive parts and C1/C2 are still effective) but without C3/C4 it's not at it's full potential (also: the input plug is embedded and has a ground lead which is forbidden.

There *are* groundless input filters (for medical use) but they are less effective and quite expensive. Also there's still the issue of the power supply (which probably has the same topology inside).

What's the recommended way to filter the mains supply without ground? should I simply put 'more' LC filtering action between the line or is there some other technique?

Comment: If I got it correctly the theory is to dump to neutral (which is ground at the end of the line)… just hope their plug is polarized then (the europlug fit in both ways for example).

Comment: No it is done identically in devices that have unpolarized plugs. Imagine for example all the TVs, media players, phone chargers etc - they extremely rarely have ground terminal on mains input.

Answer (score 1):

The standard procedure is to have a Y cap between isolated output side common terminal and mains input side  common terminal to suppress high frequency common mode interference. But as explained in the comments it will also make the isolated output to float capacitively at mains frequency, the capacitance just needs to be low enough to not allow too much leakage current through it for safety reasons.

Otherwise the mains input can just have the chokes and X capacitors between live and neutral, just without the Y caps to protective earth.

These 2 prong filters may just be more rare as separate components as typically they are integrated directly onboard a power supply PCB inside consumer equipment.

Comment: medical input modules are in fact done that way, there's not even the X-cap discharge resistor

Answer (score 1):

> *What's the recommended way to filter the mains supply without ground?*

The recommended way is to analyse the potential victim i.e. analyse the circuit connected to the right hand side of your input filter (not disclosed) and, see what that undisclosed circuit might be susceptible to and, whether it can deal with common-mode transients like indirect lightning (L and N to real earth).

If the potential victim **can** cope without common-mode suppression to earth then that's fine. If it can't you might consider using an isolation transformer.

Analyse threats and analyse potential victims.

> *For EMC purposes we use an input filter (commercially bought).*

You might be falling into the trap of believing your filter is used exclusively to cut-down on EMC and allow an undisclosed product to pass EMC tests. The "filter" in your question will also deal with indirect lightning surges using C3 and C4. So, C3 and C4 have dual use.

Comment: The 'victim' is in fact the rest of the world since I need to filter *emissions* from my power supply. However +1 for the transient potential for C3 and C4

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio you really do need to provide more information if you want a decent answer. Are you saying that what is to the left of the above circuit looks like a noisy version of standard L-N-E or are you saying something else here? If your output connects to the left of the above circuit then what access to earth does that circuit have and, what sort of noise does it produce. If your power supply (to the left) already suppresses the likelihood of indirect lightning then you need to reveal that.

Answer (score 0):

Even Class II PSUs have an RF path to the mains distribution across their insulation transformer. I.e. you dump the RF common-mode noise into your local floating circuit ground. This ground is RF-attached to mains via the Y-caps across the insulation. The only drawback is, that your DC circuit will float around ~100VAC at the mains frequency. But this is usually no EMI concern. Also note, that you only need to return such RF current which originated at "earth" (e.g. ESD). Any local circuit RF-current is returned within your isolated circuit.

It doesn't matter whether the RF noise is returned to the Neutral of Live wire of the mains cabling. Remember you are talking about RF common-mode noise. For such currents there are no separate wires in the cabling. It flows on all the cables. Such noise also doesn't care if there is a 200V DC difference between the two wires. In other words the stray capacitance between the mains wires is sufficient to make them look shorted together for RF common-mode noise. If you worry, just add a 1 nF Y-cap between the two mains wires to intentionally RF-short them.